# Finding count of occurrences from a table of unique values

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a movie database with three tables. Filmparticipation, Person and Filmcharacter

My problem is that I have to find every actor that has acted as a unique character in over 200 movies.

An unique character, is an character that only shows up once in the filmcharacter table.

I think that I have found the table of unique characters with the following query

```
SELECT filmcharacter.partid FROM filmcharacter GROUP BY 
filmcharacter.partid HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

I rewrite this as a WITH statement in the form of

```
WITH unique_table(partid) AS (SELECT partid FROM filmcharacter GROUP 
BY partid HAVING count(*) = 1)
```

However I am unsure how to further solve this problem. I was planning on using WITH to create a table with the data that I need, then selecting the rows that I want, joining them with relevant things.

```
   WITH unique_table(partid) AS (SELECT partid FROM filmcharacter 
   INNER 
   JOIN filmparticipation ON(filmcharacter.partid = 
   filmparticipation.partid) INNER JOIN person(person.personid = 
   filmparticipation.personid) GROUP 
   BY partid)
```

I'm not sure how to move onwards next I have tried

```
   WITH unique_table(partid) AS (SELECT partid FROM filmcharacter 
   INNER 
   JOIN filmparticipation ON(filmcharacter.partid = 
   filmparticipation.partid) INNER JOIN person(person.personid = 
   filmparticipation.personid) GROUP 
   BY partid) SELECT * FROM unique_table GROUP BY partid HAVING 
   count(partid) > 200;
```

But If send that, I get query zero tables.

The tables have the following keys:

```
Filmparticipation(personid, partid)

Filmcharacter(partid)

Person(personid)
```

What I expect to get is something along the lines of a table. That has an Id that identifies the actor (personid) and the count of times they have appeared acting as a unique character

```
  Actor       Count
----------|----------
     1        201
     2        309
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. Then compose a new overall query. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the table `person` with `filmparticipation` and use `not exists` to ensure that the same `partid` does not occur another time in the `filmparticipation`:

```
select p.personid, count(*) as `count`
from person p
inner join filmparticipation fp on fp.personid = p.personid
where not exists (
    select 1
    from filmparticipation fp1
    where fp1.partid = fp.partid and fp.personid != p.personid
)
group by p.personid
having count(*) > 200
```

If you are running MySQL 8.0, this can also be achieved with a window count:

```
select personid, count(*)
from (
    select p.personid, count(*) over(partition by fp.partid) cnt
    from person p
    inner join filmparticipation fp on fp.personid = p.personid
) x
where cnt = 1
group by person_id
having count(*) > 200
```